# I am trying to get a simpler method to obtain summary of values against each type in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains 7800 rows and 2 columns. The columns are loan type and outstanding value. I am looking to print a dataframe which will provide me the loan types and the outstanding.

```
Loan_Type   Outstanding_Value
Home Loan   $500000
Auto Loan   $3000 
Home loan   $300000
Over Draft  $10000
Home Loan   $100000
```

I tried using,

```
result=df['Loan_Type'].unique(),df['Outstanding_Value'].sum()
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Loan_Type').sum()`?

Comment: nope.. it did not work.gives me TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @HarrySmith It will work, you just made a mistake. Based on that error you probably accidentally used `[]` instead of `()`. There are parentheses to specify the group keys: df.groupby **(** 'Loan_Type' **)**, not brackets.

Comment: Thanks, @ALollz  it's my bad got the brackets incorrect

Comment: @ALollz, is there a way to do this with original dataframe without dropping "NA" values under ('Loan_Type')?